# jQuery : check if label by a specific name exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

check if label by a specific name exists,

Say if i want to find if such label exists

```
<label onClick='javascript:someMethod()' name="label_name">*some text*</label>
```

if so then i need to implement some code.

Comment: Do you want to know if does exist a Label with name="label_name" ? or if does exist a label with *some text*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This in condition loop -- $('label[name="label_name"]').length

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
var x = $('label[name="label_name"]');
if(x.length){
    //label exists
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($('label[name="label_name"]').length) {
    alert('Label exists');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if($('label[name="label_name"]').length)
{
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var name=$("label").attr("name");
    });
```